# Authentication when adding 3rd party auth with same email to an existing account

Tags: authentication, oauth

Are there any security risks adding 3rd party authentication (Google, FB, etc.) to existing account based on matching email without re-authentication?

Let's say user already have an account with the@email.com, but later:

1. decides to login/sign-up with FB OAuth which uses the same the@email.com. Should we require user to re-authenticate with existing login credentials before adding FB auth to existing account or just automatically add FB auth as another login option and login user into account?

   **All websites I have used, just added 3rd Party auth to existing account with the same email and log them in automatically.*
2. logged in user goes to account setting and choose to add e.g. Google OAuth, which may or may not have the same email address. Should there be any prompt to re-authenticate user with any existing login options attached to account? 
   *e.g. Stackoverflow gives you ability to add Google OAuth from Settings (even with different email) and doesn't require you to authenticate or send any notification emails.*